# How to retrieve tx object within contract

Tags: smart-contract, contract-development

I'm trying to retrieve tx within contract, but I only can find tx_hash using read_transaction. Anybody can help me?

Comment: You can get complete transaction object by `read_transaction`. How did you call it?